# Unir filas que tienen un campo duplicado y otra columnas con datos diferentes y convertirlo en uno solo

Tags: sql, join

tengo un pequeño query con la sentencia case when, el cual me coloca en dos columnas información de un cliente, quisiera unir estas filas a una sola si un cliente tiene dos datos en cada una de estas columnas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el ejemplo: la fila 7 y 8 tiene el mismo cliente, pero valores en distintas columnas, quisiera ponerlos solo en una fila, estuve intentado con left join, pero no me sale, alguien que me apoye, gracias

Comment: ¿Cómo se comporta si simplemente quitas (b.cod_producto) del group by.

Comment: Me muestra el siguiente mensaje:

Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 27
Column 'TB_CLIENTE_PRESTAMOS.COD_PRODUCTO' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Prueba a quitar b.cod_producto del groupby y mete los case en un sum...
No suelo usar los case , asi que no estoy seguro de la sintaxis.

Comment: Gracias, me salio cambiando el codigo como indicabas, agregue la imagen en la pregunta formulada de esta pagina, gracias

Comment: el codigo va como imagen... la respuesta va en el campo respuesta y explicada..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si dejas el b.cod_producto en el group_by siempre te lo va a separar.
Aprovechando que una de los case siempre va a ser 0 , puedes sumarlos sin que afecte al resultado.

No estoy seguro de la sintaxis pero creo que seria algo como:

```
select a.codigo, a.sexo,
sum(case when b.cod_producto = ‘p001’ them sum(b.desembolso) else 0 end as prestamo_personal),
sum(case when b.cod_producto = ‘v001’ them sum(b.desembolso) else 0 end as prestamo_vehicularl),
from tb_cliente_prestamos b on a.codigo= b.codigo
where b.cod_producto in (‘p001’,’v001’)
group by a.codigo, a.sexo
order by a.codigo
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias, lo solucione con lo mencionado